# Equivalent definition of "immersion"

Tags: manifolds

Definition:

> Let $M^m$ and $N^n$ be differentiable manifolds. A differentiable mapping $\varphi : M \to N$ is said to be an *immersion* if $d\varphi_p : T_p M \to T_{\varphi(p)}N$ is injective for all $p \in M$.

Example:

> The curve $\alpha : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $\alpha(t)=(t^3,t^2)$ is a differentiable mapping but is not an immersion.

And apparently it is because we need that $\alpha'(t) \not=0$, but $\alpha'(t)=0$ at $t=0$.

How is it that $\alpha'(t)\not=0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ is equivalent to the given definition of an immersion?

(I am new to the study of manifolds, so this is probably a basic question that I'm asking.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\alpha: \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}^2$, $d\alpha_p$ is injective iff its rank is $1$. $d\alpha_t$ is given by the matrix $(3t^2, 2t)^T$. At $t=0$, we see that $d\alpha_t = (0,0)^T$, which has rank $0$; thus, $d\alpha_0$ is not injective, and so $\alpha$ is not an immersion.

Now, in this case, it turns out that the map is injective iff it is nonzero (this is *not* true in general). That's simply because the dimension of the domain is $1$, and so the rank is either $0$ or $1$. In the former case, $d\alpha_p$ is zero; in the latter case, $\alpha$ is an immersion.

Comment: Could $\alpha(t) = (t,t^2)^T$ be an immersion from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$ because $d\alpha_t = (1,2t)^T \not= (0,0)^T$? Namely, this $d\alpha_t$ will always have rank $1$?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

The differential of $\alpha:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ at $t \in \mathbb{R}$ coincides with (i.e., may be "naturally identified" with) the usual derivative.  In other words: $d\alpha_t = \alpha'(t)$.  A linear map $\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow V$ from the real line into any vector space is injective precisely when it is nonzero. Thus, $\alpha$ is an immersion if for all $t$, we have $\alpha(t) \ne 0$.